# User function for FastReports Pro VCL says "Too Many Actual Parameters" when using a C++ function

Tags: delphi, c++builder, fastreport

I am trying to setup FastReports Pro to decode a field by using a user function.

In my main form constructor, I set:

```cpp
frxReport1->AddFunction(_D("void ChangeReportField(String fieldstr, String otherfieldstr)"));
```

In the FastReports code tab using `C++Script`, I have:

```cpp
void MasterData1OnBeforePrint(TfrxComponent Sender)
{
    ChangeReportField(<frxDBDataset1."Field1">, <frxDBDataset1."Field2">);                                                                                                   
}
```

I also have the `OnUserFunction` event of the `TfrxReport` component configured:

```cpp
Variant __fastcall TMainForm::frxReport1UserFunction(const UnicodeString MethodName, Variant &Params)
{ }
```

When I try to run the report, I get this error message:

> Too Many Actual Parameters

pointing to the left parentheses of the `ChangeReportField(` in `MasterData1OnBeforePrint()`

I know this function currently doesn't do anything because it doesn't return a value. I'll get to that once I get it actually working (calling the user function).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

When added as a Pascal function, it works:

```cpp
frxReport1->AddFunction(_D("procedure ChangeReportField(fieldstr, otherfieldstr:String)"));
```